# How to blur a selective value within a function in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I would like to just blur a selective value within a word pattern

I have a custom Ace function say "load", which gets auto completed when the user selects a certain function

e.g. load (1234)

I would like to blur just the contents within the "load" function, in the above case it would be 1234. So that the contents are not visible.

I am able to blur the editor (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/266), but not sure how to blur a certain field.

Comment: what do you mean by blur? apply css filter like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter?

Comment: I don't want the user to read the value (much like how we hide passwords)

Comment: Any inputs would be appreciated !

Comment: do you use a custom mode or an existing mode?